# Why did I lose 100 reputation on SO?

Tags: support, lost-reputation

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884780/website-help-creating-a-better-chatroulette) was asked on StackOverflow to which I flagged for moderator attention because it was too vague a question for SO, a question that was clearly subjective.  After flagging, I made a comment which could be considered innappropriate.  I lost 100 reputaion for the comment.  I don't contest losing any of the reputation I received while having my comment upvoted, but I think it was unecessary for me to lose ALL of my reputation up to this point.

I guess this is just me pleading for mercy. I'm sorry and it won't happen again.

Comment: no, no. you didn't make a comment. you posted an answer. had you made a comment you wouldn't lost any rep, and might be just told off by mods. Anyway, you had altogether 25 rep. You could earn it back quite quickly.

Comment: I think that it's automatic procedure if enough people flag comment.

Comment: Your points have been automatically docked and unless you keep doing it I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You posted your comment as an answer. Six users flagged it as offensive, and it was deleted by the system. When this happens you are penalized 100 points.

Comment: @Balus - Nuts are solid; "in a nutshell" is more practical ;)

Comment: In a nutshell :) **be nice**. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

It was a totally useless answer; however IMO, it would have deserved a few downvotes, but by no means such a flagging. Somebody is being very sensitive today.

However, I'm not sure whether flags can be lifted at all, or at least not without some huge amount of administratorial action. Seeing as you lost only 25 points, I'd say shrug it off. You can get it all back with one good answer.