# Remove comment upvote and flag buttons on locked posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, comment-flags, locked-questions

Locked posts do not have upvote, downvote or flag buttons. Thus the UI clearly communicates that you cannot do these actions.

[image: Example of no buttons on locked post]

However, the upvote and flag buttons are still shown on comments, giving the impression that you *can* still upvote or flag them.

[image]

...but you can't.

[image]

Why not just remove the buttons, instead of popping up a big ugly message after they have already been clicked? This would improve the UX in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with this. Locked posts removes the up/down vote icons, so why not comment votes and flags as well?

Comment: @lostsock Interesting. I would still say it would make sense to remove the upvote button.

Comment: @lostsock http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195527/error-message-says-i-cant-flag-but-yes-i-can :)